# How to manage subscriptions on Bot Facebook Messenger with Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, bots, messenger

I'm starting on Microsoft Bot Framework and I want to create a bot like CNN's Bot to send news to subscribers, but I didn't find out a way to do that. On `flowxo.com` you can create a similar bot, but I want to create it with Microsoft Bot Framework.